# Pymongo and stored javascript

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a stored javascript function in db.system.js, call it `my_func` and it accepts 2 arrays of strings as arguments.

How can I call it from pymongo? For example calling

```
my_func(['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'])
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something as

```
...
database_connection = conn.my_database
# Here is the magic:
print database_connection.system_js.my_func(['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'])
```

And it just works!

Here is the documentation of the `system_js` attribute: http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/database.html#pymongo.database.Database.system_js

Comment: Note: By `database_connection` i want to refer to a instance of `pymongo.database.Database`