# Call MongoDB stored function from pymongo

Tags: javascript, python, mongodb, pymongo, stored-functions

I have the following function stored in mongodb:

```
db.system.js.save({
    _id: "testFunc",
    value: function() {
        return db.clients.find_one({}, {"_id" : False});
    }
});
```

How do I call the function above from python using pymongo?
I have already tried `db.eval('testFunc')` and it doesn't work. The method is deprecated.

Comment: If I read the doc correctly, it should be `db.system_js.testFunc()`.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16774889/pymongo-and-stored-javascript

Comment: Unfortunately, I have tested that method too and it does not work.

Comment: HOW does it "not work"?

Comment: Is this a real function? It's a simple [findOne](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/) - there is no need for a stored function.

Comment: The purpose was to understand how to call a stored function in mongodb from python. The above function is just for testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`eval`, `system_js` etc. [are all deprecated.](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrate-to-pymongo4.html?highlight=system_js#removed-features-with-no-migration-path)

While you [can still create javascript functions on the server](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/), it comes with a clear warning:

> Do not store application logic in the database. There are performance
> limitations to running JavaScript inside of MongoDB. Application code
> also is typically most effective when it shares version control with
> the application itself.